# Hidden content running into footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a problem when showing my `display:none;` hidden content with jquery show/hide.  When I show the hidden content it runs into my footer because my `position:relative;` parent `.wrapper` doesn't know the height of the `position:absolute;` child `#learninfo` ``` #promoteinfo``#networkinfo ``` `#performinfo`.  When the screen display is bigger (like normal window size for macbook pro) it's no problem but the smaller the screen the more text runs into my footer and even below if text runs past `<footer>`. The code I'm using is (I do use some foundation + `SASS`)

HTML

```
<ul class="idm-mission">
        <h2>
        <li id="learn">LEARN</li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li id="promote">PROMOTE</li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li id="network">NETWORK</li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li id="perform">PERFORM</li>
        </h2>
      </ul>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="learninfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="promoteinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="networkinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="performinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- End of content -->
<!-- footer html below -->
<footer>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#learninfo,#promoteinfo,#networkinfo,#performinfo {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fcb702;
    width: 100%;
}
#learn:hover,#promote:hover,#network:hover,#perform:hover {
    color: $primary-color;
}
footer {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: rem-calc(100px);
    text-align: left;
}
```

jQuerY

```
// Learn information display 
$("#learn").hover(function (e) {
//This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or ho
$("#learninfo").show();



}, function (e) {
//This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over.
$("#learninfo").hide();

});



// Promote information display 
$("#promote").hover(function (e) {
//This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or ho
$("#promoteinfo").show();


}, function (e) {
//This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over.

$("#promoteinfo").hide();

});



// Network information display 
$("#network").hover(function (e) {
//This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or ho
$("#networkinfo").show();


}, function (e) {
//This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over.

$("#networkinfo").hide();

});



// Perform information display 
$("#perform").hover(function (e) {
//This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or ho
$("#performinfo").show();


}, function (e) {
//This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over.

$("#performinfo").hide();

});
```

Comment: Can you put a working example of the problem in to http://jsfiddle.net. Any UI issue like this is hard to diagnose without seeing the problem.

Comment: you can also use the `.toggle('selector')` to make the element show/hide

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YqBbm/ although I don't know how to set the jQuerY doc ready because I always use the $.foundation which is the same thing but it won't work in jfiddle since foundation isn't present so if you tell me how to edit the $.ready in for it to work properly I will do so so you can see it how I do.

Comment: learned how to properly add the ready statement outside of foundation so you can see what the problem is hopefully.. http://jsfiddle.net/YqBbm/1/

Answer (score 0):

replace this part of your CSS and you're good to go:

```
#learninfo,#promoteinfo,#networkinfo,#performinfo {
    visibility:hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: #fcb702;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**reasons why it's happening:**

the absolute positioned element doesn't get considered into the height calculation of the parent `relative` content, therefor it's better to use `position:relative;` in order to get it into the calculation.

`display:none;` literally hides the element from the code, therefor it can not be calculated into the height of the parent, so use `visibility:hidden;` instead to only make it invisible to the user and still get considered in the calculations.

P.S. while you're at it, replace these parts of your jQuery:

```
$("#learninfo").show();
```

with:

```
$("#learninfo").css('visibility','visible');
```

and

```
$("#learninfo").hide();
```

with:

```
$("#learninfo").css('visibility','hidden');
```

and the same for other `show()` and `hide()` functions.

**UPDATE:**

if you don't want the space to be displayed, then you only need to change the position to relative, see the working example => http://jsfiddle.net/G64Bs/1/

if you distinctly want to use the `absolute` position then you need to control the height of the parent div using jQuery, where you have to ask another question, or see the other examples over the net.

Comment: If I do `visibility:hidden;` then it will take up the space even while it's invisible I'm trying to use `display:none` so that it won't take up the space when invisible.

Comment: Trying it now having a couple problems maybe you could help me implement those changes http://jsfiddle.net/YqBbm/1/ (and in your fiddle you used `display:none` not `visibility:hidden` I really don't mind which one I use but I don't want it to take up space when hidden.

Comment: doesn't work in live environment idk why it works in fiddle but it makes everything jumpy/choppy.  That is why I did the positioning like that in the first place because it was mentioned that it was a fix when it happens.  How do I make a `visibility:hidden;` div not take up space?

Comment: in order to make it "not jumpy" you need to give the `show()` and `hide()` functions some duration to make it kinda animated ==> http://jsfiddle.net/YqBbm/4/

Comment: Still messes up my footer and gets all choppy I actually tried most of this stuff already.  It makes me just want to send you the folder with the elements so you can see what I'm talking about.  Would that be alright? It's not huge it's just one html page.

Comment: alright, email it to me if you need to, but please note that when you change the size of your wrapper, the position of the footer will change and that is inevitable, so it will jump a bit, unless you use `visibility:hidden;` to reserves the space so it wouldn't jump!

Comment: Just sent it to the email on your contact page of your website (which is very nice by the way).

Comment: ok I got your email, but there seems to be no problem? can you illustrate what you exactly desire or what seems to be the problem for you?

Comment: When the screen is smaller the wrapper doesn't adjust height because it doesn't know the height of the hidden relative div and runs into the footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are specifying a new position rule in the child divs of wrapper. Let the child divs inherit the position from wrapper div

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#learninfo,#promoteinfo,#networkinfo,#performinfo {
    display: none;
    position: inherit;
    color: #fcb702;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's absolutely positioned inside of a relative parent for jquery show/hide purposes so this won't work for me.

Comment: I just ran your code with the same thing and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: I just ran your code with the same thing and it worked perfectly:

Comment: It just looks like it on jsfiddle I tried it that way first and thought the same thing but doesn't work with the jquery show/hide for some reason. Makes it choppy and messes my footer up in the real environment.  I read the documentation and have a couple jquery books that explained how to fix this problem and it's the reason I have parent relative child absolute.  Make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should try somthing bellow code (jQuery code for this purpose)

```
 $("SelectelementByIDClassOrOTHER").css("display","inline");//first select your require element and set css as inline or block according to your need.
     $("SelectelementByIDClassOrOTHER").css("display","block");//
```